# In Fatal Exception (Unable to add window) : What does "input channel is not allowed" mean?

Tags: android

Got this Stack Trace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@412b2fb0 -- input channel is not allowed
           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:683)
           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2971)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I already have searched for the problem but couldn't find similar.  Note that this isn't a `is not valid; is your activity running?` or `permission denied for this window type` issue.

What I'm not getting is `-- input channel is not allowed` and how to solve this. What causes the crash and what to do to prevent this. This crash occurs very less frequently in my app. It's not reproducing much.

I'm not posting any code because even I'm not sure where to look for the problem.

Comment: Have you resolve your issue?

Comment: Not yet. If you get the solution let me know.

Comment: I am meet the same issue but not any solution about it .